# How to access iPhone contact details in my sample application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I access iPhone contact details in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the AddressBook APIs to get iPhone's contacts. It is easy to find code snippets.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [ABAddressBook API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html). There's an [introduction here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744).