# Integrate the iPhone call functionality with my sample application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, call, message

I would like to integrate the iPhone call functionality with my sample application. I have researched and found a way to integrate the call functionality with my application from Stack Overflow question *[Make a call from my iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282778)*.

Also, in Stack Overflow question *[How to access iPhone contact details in my sample application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721848)*, I have found a way to show available contacts in my application from the below link using the AddressBook [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

However, I didn't find any coding to integrate "**Decline, busy, answer, text message, text message reply, etc.**" functionality with my sample application.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot handle a telephone call within your iPhone application; it is limited by iOS. You can consider [VoIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) calls which you can handle within your application.